# What does 'require' do when defining strong parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple app with a user model, this is its table:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email"
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  .
  .
  .
end
```

In `users_controller`, we normally define a private method `user_params` to pass permitted parameter, for example:

```
 params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
```

My question is about the `require`. In [rubyonrails' api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require), it says:

"When passed a single key, if it exists and its associated value is either present or the singleton false ...... When given an array of keys, the method tries to require each one of them in order. If it succeeds, an array with the respective return values is returned ...... Otherwise, the method re-raises the first exception found..."

But in the previous example's `app/views/users/new.html.erb` page, if I leave the `:name` column blank, I still can successfully submit. I tried to change the line like this:

```
params[:user].permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
```

It still works. Although there's a bit difference when passing the parameter key `:user`.

---

Rails can check a column's presence by using validation in model.rb. Does the `require` here do the similar thing ?
What's the difference between these two usages?  Could anyone explain a bit, or give a simple example?

Thank you!

Comment: The `:name` is one of the keys passed in `permit`, not to `require`. Try passing the `params` without `:user` key and you will see the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) strong parameters:

> Allows you to choose which attributes should be whitelisted for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed

By defining

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
```

you `require` the params to have `user` and `permit` the user contain several fields. If either you or third-party request doesn't contain `user` a meaningful exception will be raised:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

Try not to pass `user` when you have the following code in the controller:

```
params[:user].permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
```

You'll receive classical `undefined method permit for nil:NilClass` that's way less readable

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thank you @Igor Drozdov . I found this "Provides two methods for this purpose: require and permit. The former is used to mark parameters as required. The latter is used to set the parameter as permitted and limit which attributes should be allowed for mass updating.".  Based on your answer, I realized both `require` and `permit` only care about the parameter hash's `:key`. So it actually dosen't care whether the `:key`'s value is nil. And the `require` means in the parameter hash there must be a key named `:user`, if there's not, it would raise a missing key exception. Am I understand right?

Comment: yea, you're right. and `permit` just fetches the enlisted keys from the `params[:user]`